# How do I show all variable in my PDF output in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to display all the variables and rows of the uploaded table using the head() function in my pdf output. Does anyone know how I can do that? Right now the output shows like this when I just use the head() function.

[image]

Comment: `head(as.data.frame(student_clean))`?

Comment: @AllanCameron yup!!! Looks like that worked! Thanks!